# Selecionar e somar registros de uma tabela com campos diferentes

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde pessoal, mais uma vez venho pedir um auxilio!

Tenho uma tabela com os jogos realizados e os placares, preciso mostrar quantos jogos ja foram realizados e o numero de gols sofridos e realizados e etc, o problema e que a tabela possui o time mandante e o time visitante, não estou conseguindo printar na tela apenas os resultados de juntos do mesmo time, no exemplo do sql esta somente a tentativa de mostrar um time por linha, depois tentarei os resultados restantes conforme a imagem

Para entender melhor segue o exemplo.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabela` (
  `id_tabela` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_competicoes_tabela` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mandante_tabela` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `visitante_tabela` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `data_tabela` date NOT NULL,
  `hora_tabela` time NOT NULL,
  `local_tabela` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `placar_mandante_tabela` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `placar_visitante_tabela` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ativa_tabela` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `alterado_tabela` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tabela`
--

INSERT INTO `tabela` (`id_tabela`, `id_competicoes_tabela`, `mandante_tabela`, `visitante_tabela`, `data_tabela`, `hora_tabela`, `local_tabela`, `placar_mandante_tabela`, `placar_visitante_tabela`, `ativa_tabela`, `alterado_tabela`) VALUES
(10, 26, 10, 11, '2016-07-23', '15:30:00', 8, 6, 3, 0, 0),
(11, 25, 11, 9, '2016-07-22', '14:00:00', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(12, 25, 9, 8, '2016-07-16', '17:30:00', 9, 5, 2, 0, 0),
(13, 25, 11, 10, '2016-07-13', '01:00:00', 9, 4, 1, 0, 1),
(14, 27, 8, 10, '2016-07-15', '14:00:00', 8, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(15, 27, 11, 9, '2016-07-30', '19:00:00', 9, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(16, 27, 9, 8, '2016-07-20', '20:00:00', 10, 5, 2, 0, 1),
(17, 26, 8, 11, '2016-07-23', '00:30:00', 10, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(18, 27, 10, 11, '2016-07-23', '00:30:00', 9, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(19, 25, 11, 8, '2016-07-28', '02:00:00', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

E esta e a consulta

```
    SELECT * FROM tabela 
WHERE alterado_tabela = 1 
AND id_competicoes_tabela = 27 
GROUP BY concat(mandante_tabela,visitante_tabela) 
ORDER BY data_tabela
```

Terei que exibir o resultado mais ou menos assim

[image: Tabela]

Comment: select case when (placar_mandante_tabela > placar_visitante_tabela) then 'v' 
            when (placar_mandante_tabela = placar_visitante_tabela) then 'e'
   else 'd' end) resultado
from tabela 
where mandante_tabela = '1'  
union all 
select case when (placar_mandante_tabela > placar_visitante_tabela) then 'd' 
            when (placar_mandante_tabela = placar_visitante_tabela) then 'e'
   else 'v' end) resultado
from tabela 
where visitante_tabela = '1'    ideia inicial

Comment: Provavelmente terá que fazer um union duplicado sua tabela from, sendo o primeiro tabelaMandante e segundo tabelaVisitante, e em cada union ter a as colunas referente do seu placar.

Comment: Pensei na Union, mais achei que iria deixar mais lento o processo, mais vou ver o que ira sair aqui!

Comment: Motta, olhei seu exemplo e na boa, heheh, deu um nó na minha cabeça, vou pegar e estudar ele para ver se aprendo mais, nunca imaginei que daria para realizar a consulta desta forma!!

Comment: Somar ou contar? `Select SUM(registros) from tabela` ou `Select COUNT(registros) from tabela` ?

Answer (score 0):

Valeu pessoal, consegui uma solução mais viável, e acho que não ira pesar muito na hora da consulta!

Criei uma tabela temporária onde e gravada toda vez que existe uma alteração ou inserção de um novo jogo, assim consulto somente ela, sem precisar de realizar subselects, funcionou certinho.

Obrigado pela ajuda!!